# java get the coordinate with random angle

Tags: java

i'm writing a program that click JPanel and then a circle will spawn then its x & y will add 10 pixel per frame. The following two lines are temporarily to determine the next step after the circle spawn.

```
    destinationX = -10 + (int)(Math.random() * ((10 - (-10)) + 1));
    destinationY = -10 + (int)(Math.random() * ((10 - (-10)) + 1));
```

The above code is not the best to determine the position of the second steps of the cirlce. I want apply a method which make possibilities much more even. The following way is i about to do.....

```
           x2,y2     
             /
            /
           /
          /
         /
      h /
       /
      / a
      ----------------------------
   x1,y1
```

x1,y2 are known, a is random 360 degrees, h is 10, how to cal x2, y2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you familiar with trigonometry? You have drawn a right triangle with `h` as the hypotenuse, `a` as the angle in question, an imaginary leg opposite (`opp`) of the angle, and a leg adjacent (`adj`) to the angle. Here's an updated diagram:

```
           x2,y2     
             /|
            / |
           /  |
          /   |
         /    | opp
      h /     |
       /      |
      / a     |
      ---------
   x1,y1  adj
```

Trigonometry defines a function
*sine* (`sin`) as `opp / h` and a similar function
*cosine* (`cos`) as `adj / h`.

In your case, you want to compute `x2 = x1 + adj`.
Since `cos(a) = adj / h`,
`adj = h * cos(a)`; so by substitution we arrive at
`x2 = x1 + h * cos(a)`.

We can do a similar derivation for `y2` and get `y2 = y1 + h * sin(a)`.

If you want to move a point by a fixed amount in a random direction, you need `Math.sin` and `Math.cos`:

```
double angle = Math.toRadians(Math.random() * 360);
double amount = 10;
int x2 = x1 + (int)(amount * Math.cos(angle));
int y2 = y1 + (int)(amount * Math.sin(angle));
```

Comment: why not { angle = Math.random() * 2 * Math.PI; } ?